# How to mapping a file in the directory and move separately to other folder using Python?

Tags: python, loops, directory, mapping, move

I would like to do extract 7z file, first I've to checking whether the 7z file exist or not, do the extraction, then mapping a specific file in those extracted folder then move the extracted folder based on the result. If the file that I mapped exist on the folder, then move to valid folder otherwise move to invalid folder.
I have done some code, but still got a problem how to move the invalid folder.

Here is what I've done.

This is the config.py

```
RAW_DIR = "E:/data/raw"
OUTPUT_DIR = "E:/data/output"
RESULT_DIR = "E:/data/output/output"
VALID_DIR = "E:/data/valid"
INVALID_DIR = "E:/data/invalid"

RAW_IDENTIFIER = "E:/data/raw/*_zipfile.7z"
VALID_IDENTIFIER = "/system/result/processing.log"
```

This the main.py

```
import time
import glob
import shutil
import os.path
import config as cfg
from pyunpack import Archive

# Extract
for i, f in enumerate(glob.glob(os.path.join(cfg.RAW_DIR, cfg.RAW_IDENTIFIER))):
    timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    output_path = cfg.RESULT_DIR + str(i) + "_" + timestamp
    os.mkdir(output_path)
    Archive(f).extractall(output_path)

    # Mapping
    for folder in enumerate(glob.glob(output_path + cfg.VALID_IDENTIFIER)):
        shutil.move(output_path, cfg.VALID_DIR)
        file = glob.glob(cfg.OUTPUT_DIR + "/output*")
        file_name = os.path.basename(file)
        shutil.move(file_name, cfg.INVALID_DIR)
```

Anyone can help me please. Thank's a lot

Comment: To extract a .7z file, you'll need to use a third party library. StackOverflow is not the place to ask for recommendations for libraries, but a quick Google search will turn up a few.

Comment: @Grismar I think the author is not asking for any third part lib rather for the way to copy file from one dir to another

Comment: Ah I didn't notice you were already using `pyunpack` - you already have `shutil.move(file_name, cfg.INVALID_DIR)`, but your code seems to have some other errors - what exactly is your question here?